# Routes cannot be defined using annotations

Tags: php, symfony

I'm currently using Symfony 4.4 with annotations for routing.

`path` twig function cannot detect route names which are created with annotations.I tried to create a route using yaml configuration and it works and that means the problem comes from the annotations, right?

Why does that happen? I've run `composer require annotations` so far.Do I need something else?

```
namespace App\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;

class HomeController extends AbstractController
{
    /**
     * @Route("/", name="test")
     */
    public function index()
    {
        return $this->render('default/test.html.twig');
    }
}
```

```
<a href="{{ path('test') }}">Test Action</a> // It says undefined route
```

Comment: trying to run `bin/console debug:router` to see all available routes.
have you been registering your annotation routes at `config\routes\annotations.yaml`?. or you can try to clear the cache

Comment: `bin/console debug:route` shows all routes which means they are registered succesfully, but why `path` functon does not display them?

Comment: Ok, route is perfectly working but there are no hints using `path` function, why?

Comment: can you put `bin/console debug:router` output here?